# VB.Net command line (console) program with parameters for SharePoint

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, console

I would like to create a console program in VB.net that would allow parameters. What i would like to do is in the code below add parameters so the webpart page can be created from the Run menu. e.g. C:.......\MyProgram.exe "Design" --This would then create the Design webpart page.

I tried looking at the internet but was not very successfull. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
      Module Main

                Public Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
          Dim prj As String

                    Dim site As New SPSite("http://site/")
                    Dim web As SPWeb = site.AllWebs(0)

                    Dim list As SPList = web.Lists("ListName")

Dim postInformation As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><Method><SetList Scope=""Request"">" + list.ID.ToString + "</SetList><SetVar 
    Name=""ID"">New</SetVar><SetVar Name=""Cmd"">NewWebPage</SetVar><SetVar 
    Name=""Type"">WebPartPage</SetVar><SetVar Name=""WebPartPageTemplate"">2</SetVar><SetVar 
    Name=""Title"">" + prj.ToString + "</SetVar><SetVar 
    Name=""Overwrite"">true</SetVar></Method>"

                    Dim processBatch As String = web.ProcessBatchData(postInformation)
                 'Display the results...
                Console.WriteLine(processBatch)
                    Console.WriteLine("New Web part page added successfully")
                    Console.ReadLine()



                End Sub

        End Module
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 Public Sub Main(ByVal sArgs() As String)

    If sArgs.Length = 0 Then                'If there are no arguments
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World! <-no arguments passed->") 'Just output Hello World
    Else                                    'We have some arguments 
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        While i < sArgs.Length             'So with each argument
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " & sArgs(i) & "!") 'Print out each item
            i = i + 1                       'Increment to the next argument
        End While

    End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps, for accessing the command line arguments.

Great answer by: Rajesh Sitaraman