# How to pass 5-7 strings from one windows application to another console application in VB

Tags: vb.net

I have two applications here, one Windows Form Application and another Console Application.

I want the windows application to send,

```
"1"
"2"
"3"
"4"
"5"
"6"
"7"
```

And then the console application should receive them in,

```
Dim str1 as string = "1"
Dim str2 as string = "2"
Dim str3 as string = "3"
Dim str4 as string = "4"
Dim str5 as string = "5"
Dim str6 as string = "6"
Dim str7 as string = "7"
```

I found this code,

```
Dim str as stirng = Command()
```

and from windows application,

```
Process.Start("my path to console app.exe", "the text")
```

This works but only one parameter is passed. I know I can use Split Functions and split them out in console if I send all string together with a character in between but is there a way for me to send all of it one by one ?

I want to star the console app, wait till it is terminated and then continue the process.

Comment: I think you want interprocess communication for this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153/interprocess-communication-for-windows-in-c-sharp-net-2-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be starting the console app manually (as opposed to sending it data when it is already running), you could use command line arguments. Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642604/vb-net-command-line-console-program-with-parameters-for-sharepoint) we have the Sub Main for the console app:

```
Public Sub Main(ByVal sArgs() As String)
    If sArgs.Length = 0 Then  'If there are no arguments
        Console.WriteLine("no arguments passed")
    Else  'We have some arguments 
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < sArgs.Length  'So with each argument
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " & sArgs(i) & "!") 'Print out each item
            i = i + 1  'Increment to the next argument
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you can use:

```
Process.Start("myConsoleApp.exe", "1 2 3 4 5 6 7")
```

Comment: Thanks. But a question, "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" was just a example. My strings are longer, and may contain numbers/alphabets/special characters and spaces in them. Can I use ',' ? Right now i think the Array is separating the string by space ?

Comment: Have a look at Mark Hurd's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097872/vb-net-how-to-pass-a-string-with-spaces-to-the-command-line) for an example of how to encapsulate your individual strings in quotes. The double-double quote is the key to happiness.